# call variable from method inside the method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Having two views

views.py

```
def followup(request):
    ''''''
     marklist = report_template(request)
     return render(request, 'incident/followup.html',{'somevar':somevar})

def report_template(request):
    '''''
    report=Report.objects.filter(report=report_id)
     ''''''
    return render(request, 'incident/print.html',
        {'report':report})
```

I am calling one method inside another method.Calling report_template method into followup method.followup method also have variable to render in template.

How to pass the variable of report_template method to followup method and make it display in template.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to create a helper method that returns the `report` or the context needed by both the methods. The issue here is you are returning a `HTTPResponse` object, and it is cleanest to use helper method here:

```
def get_report(request):
    report=Report.objects.filter(report=report_id)
    #do more processing here.
    #returning a dict is probably safest here, because, in the calling method, `.get()` would not throw an error if key is not present. 
    return {'report': report, 'somevar': somevar}

def followup(request):
     marklist = get_report(request).get('somevar')
     return render(request, 'incident/followup.html',{'somevar':marklist})

def report_template(request):
    report = get_report(request).get('report')
    return render(request, 'incident/print.html',
        {'report':report})
```

Comment: Means,from report_template,whatever query set or function need to include in followup method,i need to give in get_report  method,after process return it in dict.How to render it in followup.html.

Comment: I have shown that in the example. Basically, instead of calling `report_template` method, you are calling `get_report` which is doing the processing for you. The helper method would be called from both the view methods

Comment: Clear,in followup.html i need to do like this somevar.fieldname-->of models.

Comment: exactly.. you can customize the response to cater to your specific needs

Comment: 1 doubt,in report_template method,i am getting the id of a table from ajax post.Now i want to include that function also in followup method.Need your suggestion/idea to do this.

Comment: In views,i am getting the id through request.POST.

Comment: Sure.. You are sending the `request` object in the method.. You can extract the id there are return it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33644/discussion-between-user2086641-and-karthikr)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with views, you have to look up for templatetags, which is a better way to do so in Django (a view accepts a Request argument and returns an HttpResponse variable).

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/.

Using templatetags makes your code reusable, by factoring what you do in views.

Comment: why would you do that in a templatetag ? OP is looking to follow `DRY` principles here. Also, a templatetag does __not__ return a `HttpResponse` object.

Comment: Because it seems more legit as he wants to **display** content and not only retrieves variables.